# Use SED to extract value of all input elements with a certain name

Tags: html, regex, bash, sed

How do I get the value attribute based on a search of some other attribute?

For example:

```
<body>
<input name="dummy" value="foo">
<input name="alpha" value="bar">
</body>
```

How do I get the value of the input element with the name "dummy"?

Comment: You can get it with this command. sed -n 's/.*input name="dummy" value="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p'   But for this job, a html/xml parser is the right tool

Answer (score 4):

Since you're  looking for a solution using bash and sed, I'm assuming you're looking for a Linux command line option.

## Use `hxselect` html parsing tool to extract element; use `sed` to extract value from element

I did a Google search for "linux bash parse html tool" and came across this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6389/how-to-parse-hundred-html-source-code-files-in-shell

The accepted answer suggests using the `hxselect` tool from the [html-xml-utils package](http://www.w3.org/Tools/HTML-XML-utils/) which extracts elements based on a css selector. 
So after installing (downoad, unzip, `./configure`, `make`, `make install`), you can run this command using the given css selector

```
hxselect "input[name='dummy']" < example.html
```

(Given that example.html contains your example html from the question.) This will return:

```
<input name="dummy" value="foo"/>
```

Almost there. We need to extract the value from that line:

```
hxselect "input[name='dummy']" < example.html | sed -n -e "s/^.*value=['\"]\(.*\)['\"].*/\1/p"
```

Which returns "foo".

## why you would / would not want to use this approach

- [using regex to parse out the attributes is complicated, and often the wrong way to go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231382/regular-expression-pattern-not-matching-anywhere-in-string)
- the hxselect tool (in my other answer) is a pain to install
- BUT, *this approach accepts malformed html*, which is what is argued for in [this answer to the question linked above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6638578/3012550). By the way, that question has very thorough discussion on the regex+html debate.

Comment: I came back after the fact and I really don't think this is a good answer - it's awkward and too complicated, and doesn't follow @Ramana's advice because it's still parsing the element attributes with SED. I did some more research and answered again, with a different approach

Answer (score 2):

Since you're asking for SED, I'll assume you want a command line option. However, a tool built for html parsing may be more effective. The problem with my first answer is that I don't know of a way in css to select the value of an attribute (does anyone else?). However, with xml you can select attributes like you could other elements. Here is a command line option for using an xml parsing tool.

## Treat it as XML; use [XPATH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx)

1. Install `xmlstarlet` with your package manager
2. Run `xmlstarlet sel -t -v //input[@name=\'dummy\']/@value example.html` (where example.html contains your html
3. If your html isn't valid xml, follow the warnings from xmlstarlet to make the necessary changes (in this case, `<input>` must be changed to `<input/>`
4. Run the command again. Returns: `foo`

## why you might/might not use this approach

- it is way more simple and robust than [hand-rolling a regex html parser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/3012550), but
- *it requires well formed html*

Comment: This comes with well too many warnings for my html.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing HTML with sed is generally a bad idea, since sed works in a line-based manner and HTML does not usually consider newlines syntactically important. It's not good if your HTML-handling tools break when the HTML is reformatted.

Instead, consider using Python, which has an HTML push parser in its standard library. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
from sys import argv

# Our parser. It inherits the standard HTMLParser that does most of
# the work.
class MyParser(HTMLParser):
    # We just hook into the handling of start tags to extract the
    # attribute
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        # Build a dictionary from the attribute list for easier
        # handling
        attrs_dict = dict(attrs)

        # Then, if the tag matches our criteria
        if tag == 'input' \
           and 'name' in attrs_dict \
           and attrs_dict['name'] == 'dummy':
            # Print the value attribute (or an empty string if it
            # doesn't exist)
            print attrs_dict['value'] if 'value' in attrs_dict else ""

# After we defined the parser, all that's left is to use it. So,
# build one:
p = MyParser()

# And feed a file to it (here: the first command line argument)
with open(argv[1], 'rb') as f:
    p.feed(f.read())
```

Save this code as, say, `foo.py`, then run

```
python foo.py foo.html
```

where `foo.html` is your HTML file.